# LWJGL Transparency

Tags: java, opengl, transparency, alphablending, lwjgl

I am trying to use LWJGL transparency using the command:

```
// Enable transparency
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

And transparency works, its just that a background drawn like this:

```
    // Draw Background
    glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glVertex2f(width, height);
    glVertex2f(0, height);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
```

Does not show.
I am using LWJGL 2.8.2, Eclipse Indigo, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

When rendering transparent things, you must render everything in back-to-front order. So make sure you're rendering the background *first*.

Comment: I am rendering the background first, right after a Display.sync(60);

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this is the best solution, but a way to get transparent and non-transparent content would be to deactivate/activate the GL_BLEND before drawing, like this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
drawTransparentContent();

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
drawNonTransparentContent();
```

This worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you're rendering a non textured vertices it's a good idea to do glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) . This should fix it if ur rendering things in correct order